# Trying to identify a book I read as a child; 1970's or 1980's, anthology with themes of dark fantasy and scifi

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

The book was an anthology of short stories that I read as a child in Australia. This is the key points that I remember:

- Book had a blue cover.
- Style of artwork was from 70s/80s.
- I read this in the late 90s/early 2000s and it was already old and tattered.
- Was a large format book with coloured pictures on each page.
- One story was about a weak orc/goblin who ends up killing a monster that attacks (it swallowed him and he cuts it open from the inside, it had potentially had gushing yellow blood that covered the gobli/orc person?
- One story about a family exploring a red planet. They had landed their space craft. Something happens and an ocean comes out of the planet, there are sea monsters in the water. The family on the planet had heavy machinery, like excavators. Like they were terraforming or something?
- A story about a wizards dopey/sleepy apprentice.